# FancySelect doesn't change select option

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

It is strange. I started use Fancy Select and when I'm changin option (ul>li) , the native drop down option isn't changing! I watched on it's website - it doesn't work as well. I think I can add some code for it's working, but it is very strange that plugin doesn't change it itself. If I'm wrong, tell me please.

```
<select class="basic">
  <option value="">Select something…</option>
  <option>Lorem</option>
  <option>Ipsum</option>
  <option>Dolor</option>
  <option>Sit</option>
  <option>Amet</option>
</select>

 $('.basic').fancySelect();
```

Please also suggest me what to use instead of this?

Comment: Whats the problem? see http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/SdwLM/

Comment: I just ran through all of the issues on the Github for the project. None of them have your problem, may be a jsedit would help to see what is happening

Comment: thank you guys! I used old 1.4 version!